# Part game (leg) scoring in bridge

Tags: bridge

In either "party" or "rubber" bridge scoring, what is the value of a part score when you either stop playing or come to the end of a "party" round?  Some people award 50 points for a part score, some 100 points.  Which is correct?  Is there a difference if you are vulnerable or not?

Comment: See answer by @dpmattingly below, and my comment. You have specified two different scoring mechanisms, and the answer is that it depends on which of those two scoring choices you have made.

Answer (score 1):

In Chicago, or four-deal scoring, a team gets a 100 point premium for making a part score only in the fourth and final deal of the game.  If a team is carrying a part score forward from a previous deal, and do not convert it into a game score by the end of the fourth deal, they do not receive a premium.

Comment: If you added: "In Rubber Bridge the bonus is only 50, but is earned on any unclosed rubber and not just on the last hand." Then you would have a complete answer that I could up-vote.